# About "&" use in php

Tags: php

```
$arr1 = array(1);
arr2 = $arr1;
$arr2[0]++;//$arr1[0]=1,$arr2[0]=2
```

But the following code:

```
$arr1 = array(1);
$a =& $arr1[0];
$arr2 = $arr1;
$arr2[0]++;//$arr1[0]=2,$arr2[0]=2
```

When I add `$a`, the output is different! Why does this happen?

Comment: It's reference. http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: What do you want to get from $a??

Comment: the `&` is for calling variable and passing it by reference. so it use the memory stockage of this variable not the local variable.

Comment: @NigSysTechnologies I just what to know why when i add the variable `$a`, the output is different

Comment: @G.Mansour Thank you for your answer.Can you help me to solve the lastest problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JakubMatczak
Thanks for your professional response.But I still have some question.

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2);
$a =& $arr1;
$arr2 = $arr1;
$arr2[0]++;
$arr2[1]++;
```

Why the result of `$arr1` is `array(1, 2)` not `array(2, 2)`?

Comment: Because `$arr2` is a copy of `$arr1`?

Comment: @zerkms Thanks,you can view the original question above.When `$a=&$arr1[0]`the result of `$arr1` is `array(2, 2)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how references work.

Take a closer look what happens to `$arr1` before and  after assigning a reference to `$a`

```
$arr1 = array(1);
var_dump($arr1);
$a =& $arr1[0];
var_dump($arr1);
```

The result is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } 
array(1) { [0]=> &int(1) } //it's a reference now!
```

As you can see, after making `$a` an reference, also `$arr[0]` starts being a reference.

As [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign) says:

> $a and $b point to **the same content**.

And there's important note:

> $a and $b are completely equal here. **$a is not pointing to $b or vice versa.** $a and $b are pointing to the same place.

This may be a little bit confusing at first look, but this is how it works.

Further operations of your code should be clear now:

```
$arr2 = $arr1; 
$arr2[0]++;
```

You make a copy of `$arr1`, so `$arr2[0]` is also a reference to the same value just like `$a` and `$arr1[0]`. Then by incrementing `$arr2[0]`, you're also incrementing `$a` and `$arr`[0]` (or actually incrementing target single value of these three references).

Answer (score 0):

i will explain you in simple way about = and & operator

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
$a = $b
echo $a // output is 10
echo $b // output is 10
```

reason is that = is an assignment operator it just copy the value of vaiable and out in other variable.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;
$a = & $b    // here the address of a is assign to variable b.
echo $a // output is 5
echo $b // output is 5
```

reason is that & is an reference pointer it can pick the address of vaiable and out in other variable.
when you change the value of variable any where it will change the value of other variable.

Comment: When i execute the under code,the result is different of yours.The result is `1010`.Why is it happen?